# Efficient way to get counts from a query

Tags: python

I am trying to find the occupancy of a parking lot for every time a vehicle exits. I have a data frame where each row corresponds to a parking entry and exit timestamp. The dataset is quite large and the solution I have currently takes a bit of time to process. I am able to find the occupancy by performing the following query:

`Count('Exit Time Stamp of Row n' > 'Entry Date of All Rows' & 'Exit Time Stamp of Row n' <= 'Exit Date of All Rows')`

This can be accomplished in python by creating the following function:

```
# Find the occupancy
def get_occ(df):
    count_list = []
    for exit_date in df['EXIT DATE']:
        # Perform Query, append count to list
        count = df.query("@exit_date > `ENTRY DATE` & @exit_date <= `EXIT DATE`" )['TYPE'].count()
        count_list.append(count)
    # Add counts to df
    df['OCCUPANCY'] = count_list
```

**NOTE:** 'Type' is a separate column which I am using to perform the count operation.

This unfortunately takes a very long time to process for a dataset with hundreds of thousands of rows. Any suggestions for how I can improve the time it takes to process the script?

Comment: Is using a real local SQL database an option? Downside you have to create it once but their look up should be faster for enough look ups in the long run. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work for you, but I've had good luck with this kind of a problem by reforming the data into a single list with a single time stamp column and a column saying "ENTER" and "EXIT", then sorting by the timestamp.  Now, I have a simple chronological log, and it's easy to iterate the rows to maintain the counts.

Comment: @Daraan, I can upload the Dataframe to a SQL DB and perform the same query. I'll try this shortly.

Comment: @TimRoberts, interesting: what is a quick way to accomplish this in python?

Comment: @Daraan, what is the equivalence of the query written in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was suggesting.  I print out the combined dataframe so you can see what it looks like.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1, "2022-11-01 08:00:00", "2022-11-01 17:00:00"],
    [2, "2022-11-01 09:00:00", "2022-11-01 13:00:00"],
    [3, "2022-11-01 10:00:00", "2022-11-01 16:00:00"],
    [4, "2022-11-01 11:00:00", "2022-11-01 18:00:00"],
    [5, "2022-11-01 12:00:00", "2022-11-01 14:00:00"],
    [6, "2022-11-01 13:00:00", "2022-11-01 18:00:00"],
    [7, "2022-11-01 14:00:00", "2022-11-01 16:00:00"],
    [8, "2022-11-01 15:00:00", "2022-11-01 18:00:00"],
    [9, "2022-11-01 16:00:00", "2022-11-01 17:00:00"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['id', 'ENTRY', 'EXIT'] )
df2 = df["ENTRY"].to_frame().rename(columns={"ENTRY":"timestamp"})
df2['action'] = 'enter'
df3 = df["EXIT"].to_frame().rename(columns={"EXIT":"timestamp"})
df3['action'] = 'exit'
df4 = pd.concat([df2,df3])
df4.sort_values(by='timestamp', inplace=True)
print(df4)

present = 0
for idx,row in df4.iterrows():
    if row['action'] == 'enter':
        present += 1
    else:
        present -= 1
    print("At",row['timestamp'],"room holds",present,"people")
```

Output:

```
             timestamp action
0  2022-11-01 08:00:00  enter
1  2022-11-01 09:00:00  enter
2  2022-11-01 10:00:00  enter
3  2022-11-01 11:00:00  enter
4  2022-11-01 12:00:00  enter
5  2022-11-01 13:00:00  enter
1  2022-11-01 13:00:00   exit
6  2022-11-01 14:00:00  enter
4  2022-11-01 14:00:00   exit
7  2022-11-01 15:00:00  enter
6  2022-11-01 16:00:00   exit
8  2022-11-01 16:00:00  enter
2  2022-11-01 16:00:00   exit
0  2022-11-01 17:00:00   exit
8  2022-11-01 17:00:00   exit
3  2022-11-01 18:00:00   exit
5  2022-11-01 18:00:00   exit
7  2022-11-01 18:00:00   exit

At 2022-11-01 08:00:00 room holds 1 people
At 2022-11-01 09:00:00 room holds 2 people
At 2022-11-01 10:00:00 room holds 3 people
At 2022-11-01 11:00:00 room holds 4 people
At 2022-11-01 12:00:00 room holds 5 people
At 2022-11-01 13:00:00 room holds 6 people
At 2022-11-01 13:00:00 room holds 5 people
At 2022-11-01 14:00:00 room holds 6 people
At 2022-11-01 14:00:00 room holds 5 people
At 2022-11-01 15:00:00 room holds 6 people
At 2022-11-01 16:00:00 room holds 5 people
At 2022-11-01 16:00:00 room holds 6 people
At 2022-11-01 16:00:00 room holds 5 people
At 2022-11-01 17:00:00 room holds 4 people
At 2022-11-01 17:00:00 room holds 3 people
At 2022-11-01 18:00:00 room holds 2 people
At 2022-11-01 18:00:00 room holds 1 people
At 2022-11-01 18:00:00 room holds 0 people
```